# PHP output echo wrong order

Tags: php, html

I have an issue with output in PHP I am trying to print out:
Welcome back! 
Admin
You are tester number: 3
Then underneath the buttons Logout and Comment.
But it first outputs the buttons then the text.

[Output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7DE1.jpg)

Code:

```html
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
 // session variables into local variables.
 $id = $_SESSION['id'];
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 $result = "Welcome back! <br>".$username. "<br> You are tester number: ".$id;
 echo ' <button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href="logout.php" target="_parent">Log out</button>
 <button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href="blog/post.php" target="_parent">Comment</button>
 ';

 } else {
  $result = "You are not logged in yet";

 }

?>
<?php
echo $result;
?>
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $username ;?></title>
```

Comment: Well you´re echoing the buttons before the result ... Try putting the echo with buttons below `echo $result;`

Comment: Exactly what @Daan says, change your `echo` to this: `$result .= '`

Comment: I have tried switching it other way around it is still thesame.

Comment: Did you try to change the code like I said?

Comment: @Boratzan Yes thank you!

Comment: @user6184639 Then you didn't _switch it the other way around_ like I said.

Comment: @Daan Thank you I solved it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You echo the html part for the button before echoing the Welcome text.

What you could do:

```
$result = "Welcome back! <br>".$username. "<br> You are tester number: ".$id;
$result .= ' <button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href="logout.php" target="_parent">Log out</button>
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href="blog/post.php" target="_parent">Comment</button>
';
```

Comment: @user6184639 Be careful when you mix 'delayed echoing' (store string in variable and echo it later) and directly echoing your string. That was your problem here. You should choose one and stick with it :-)

Comment: You should also define $username in the else part of your if/else statement otherwise you'll encounter an undefined variable error (you use it in the title tag but if the user isn't in the session, it won't have any value). For example : $username = 'Guest';

Answer (score 0):

you are echoing the buttons and then $result... do this:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  // session variables into local variables.
   $id = $_SESSION['id'];
   $username = $_SESSION['username'];
   $result = "Welcome back! <br>".$username. "<br> You are tester number: ".$id."</br>";
   $result.=' <button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href="logout.php" target="_parent">Log out</button><button class="btn" type="button" onclick=window.parent.location.href="blog/post.php" target="_parent">Comment</button>';

?>
<?php
   echo $result;
?>
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $username ;?></title>
```

Hope it helps.